# Statistics on a list of dictionaries considering multiples keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, count

I have a list of dicts:

```
input = [{'name':'A', 'Status':'Passed','id':'x1'},
        {'name':'A', 'Status':'Passed','id':'x2'},
        {'name':'A','Status':'Failed','id':'x3'},
        {'name':'B', 'Status':'Passed','id':'x4'},
        {'name':'B', 'Status':'Passed','id':'x5'}]
```

I want an output like :

```
output = [{'name':'A', 'Passed':'2', 'Failed':'1', 'Total':'3', '%Pass':'66%'},
          {'name':'B', 'Passed':'2', 'Failed':'0', 'Total':'2', '%Pass':'100%'},
          {'name':'Total', 'Passed':'4', 'Failed':'1', 'Total':'5', '%Pass':'80%'}]\
```

i started retrieving the different names by using a lookup :

```
lookup = {(d["name"]): d for d in input [::-1]}
names= [e for e in lookup.values()]
names= names[::-1]
```

and after using the list comprehension something like :\

```
for name in names :

name_passed = sum(["Passed" and "name" for d in input if 'Status' in d and name in d])
name_faled = sum(["Failed" and "name" for d in input if 'Status' in d and name in d])\
```

But i am not sure if there is a smartest way ? a simple loop and comparing dict values will be more simple!?

Comment: You say that the output should be a list of dictionaries. Is that the best structure - what will you do with them afterwards and what do you want to do finally with that list? Just wondering if there could be a better data structure for your results.

Comment: i will generate a csv containing the output data

Comment: @Paul M. has created the output form you would pass to [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). I'm not sure how the Total line could be included (or even if you want to). The number fields were converted to `str` but you might want to leave them as `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input entries will always be grouped according to the `"name"` key-value pair:

```
entries = [
    {"name": "A", "Status": "Passed", "id": "x1"},
    {"name": "A", "Status": "Passed", "id": "x2"},
    {"name": "A", "Status": "Failed", "id": "x3"},
    {"name": "B", "Status": "Passed", "id": "x4"},
    {"name": "B", "Status": "Passed", "id": "x5"}
]

def to_grouped(entries):
    from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter
    for key, group_iter in groupby(entries, key=itemgetter("name")):
        group = list(group_iter)
        total = len(group)
        passed = sum(1 for entry in group if entry["Status"] == "Passed")
        failed = total - passed
        perc_pass = (100 // total) * passed
        yield {
            "name": key,
            "Passed": str(passed),
            "Failed": str(failed),
            "Total": str(total),
            "%Pass": f"{perc_pass:.0f}%"
        }

print(list(to_grouped(entries)))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'Passed': '2', 'Failed': '1', 'Total': '3', '%Pass': '66%'}, {'name': 'B', 'Passed': '2', 'Failed': '0', 'Total': '2', '%Pass': '100%'}]
```

This will not create the final entry you're looking for, which sums the statistics of all other entries. Though, that shouldn't be too hard to do.